# How do I get the git branch name with sed

Tags: sed, gitlab

The branch string is `24000ACB`, how do I get that out with `sed`?

I tried `echo 'origin/releases/2400ACB 294125569b2dc926158b64115f1467f916c9 WIP' | sed 's/[origin/releases/]//g'`.

Answer (score 1):

Print the part following `origin/releases/` that contains more than one non-space characters:

```
echo 'origin/releases/2400ACB 294125569b2dc926158b64115f1467f916c9 WIP' | sed -n 's/origin\/releases\/\([^ ]\+\).*/\1/p'
```

Or print the part following the last `/` that contains more than one non-space characters:

```
echo 'origin/releases/2400ACB 294125569b2dc926158b64115f1467f916c9 WIP' | sed -n 's/.*\/\([^ ]\+\).*/\1/p'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `echo 'origin/releases/2400ACB 294125569b2dc926158b64115f1467f916c9 WIP' | sed 's/[origin/releases/]//g' | awk '{print $1}'`